# \textit sets text to slanted

Tags: equations, italic, slanted

I'm having some problems with equations in my bachelor thesis. I want to have the equation numbered and underneath in the same style written what the Letters stand for. So this is what i came up with:

```
\begin{equation}
     S_T = G \cdot I_T [Nmm^2]
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
     \textit{I_T = Torsionsflächenmoment}\\
     \textit{G=Schubmodul}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}        
    G = \frac{E}{2 \cdot (1+\nu)} [MPa]
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
    \textit{E=E-Modul}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}        
    I_T= \frac{\pi}{32} \cdot (D^4-d^4) [mm^4]
\end{equation}
```

However, when i generate the thesis file, the 5th line is itlaic (the way I want it to be), but the other two are just slanted. The thing is, if I try it in a file with just this text in the document it works fine.

[image: How it looks in the thesis file]

I just find it really strange, how it's slanted but not italic.

I'm not very good with latex, so if anyone has an idea where the error might come from, that would be really helpful.

Luisa

P.S: English is not my first language, so don't come for me ;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you provide `MWE` of your code? It will help to help you in a better way...

Comment: The font for text is different than the font for math contents. Sans serif font in italic shape looks slanted.

Comment: The formatting of `Torsionsflächenmoment` is wrong, this is obviously math mode. I wonder how you managed this get this, with your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There's a `_`. The `Torsionsflächenmoment` bit is in a `center` environment. The `I` is in sans-serif "italic", the `_` switches into math mode, and you know the rest `:-)`

Comment: @campa oh yes. Which means there are also errors ;-)

Comment: You haven't shown your setup but I guess that you have somehow set the text font to sans-serif but are still using normal font for math (which, forgive me, looks awful). The fact that the 5th line (5th in the code?) is "right" is a side effect of `_` switching into math mode, but this code will raise errors. Errors should _never_ be ignored in LaTeX. `\textit` uses the text font, and since it is sans-serif there is no italic. It would be easier to help you if you made clear how the document is supposed to look. Unless you keep mixing serif and sans-serif: then most people won't help you `;-)`

Comment: @campa Thanks, that makes sense :)

Comment: @campa A lot of textbooks I used for reference use the same style, where the main text is sans serif and equtions and mathematical expressions are in serif italics. And I actually like the distinction. Is there an easy (and clean) way to switch the text to mathmode (and being able to use linebreaks)? Otherwise I'll use sans serif for my math. (btw thanks for the quick answers it already helped me quite a bit)

Comment: I've set the whole part in serif font using {\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont ...} and it seems to be working fine now.